# Postgis: How to build query which returns points within box initially and then all the other points?

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

There is code which get from database points in bounding box for rendering on browser. Also displays list of points with attributes (name etc.)

But, when filter will be applied to the dataset I may get big count points (example around 50000). Rendering 50000 points by browser may cause performance problem. Therefore in my opinion need to apply paging algorithm (by LIMIT and OFFSET). But, first need render filtered points within browser box and then all the other.

*UPD:*
I found this variant:

```
SELECT gs.id, gs.name, ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(...)', 4326), gs.point) as contains
FROM geoms as gs
WHERE gs.name LIKE '%Berlin%'
ORDER BY contains DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you have will work for what you need but are you sure you need to display 50k points most of which are outside of the window? The standard aproach would be querying the points inside the browser box and a little around it and then load the rest when the position changes.